# Como criar uma função pra exibir os maiores números de uma arvore B em Java?

Tags: java

Pessoal tenho uma duvida, como fazer uma função que retorne o Nó com o maior valor de uma arvore B que armazena inteiros. Estou tentando adaptar o código de passeio em ordem para tentar retornar, porém só retorna null.
Na classe Node criei a seguinte função

Classe Node

```
public Node maiorValor() {
    int i;
    Node aux=null;
    for (i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
        if (this.filhos[i] != null) {
            this.filhos[i].percorrerEmOrdem();
        }
         aux = this.filhos[i]; // recebe o valor

    }
    if (this.filhos[i] != null) {
        this.filhos[i].percorrerEmOrdem();
    }

    return  aux;// retorna aux
}


}
`
```

Na Classe BTree criei a seguinte função que será chamada pela classe Main que possui uma instancia de BTree

```
public Node maiorValor() {
        int i;
        Node aux;
        if (this.isEmpty() == false) {

            aux= root.maiorValor();
            return aux;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Se é uma árvore B, então ela mantém a ordem dos elementos. Neste caso, bastaria pegar a folha mais à direita (não precisa percorrer todos os nós). Algo como `maiorValor() { if (this.filhos[this.n] == null) return this.filhos[this.n]; else return this.filhos[this.n].maiorValor(); }`

Answer (score -1):

Olá, eu não sei se entendi o que você precisa fazer, mas se você precisar pegar o maior valor de um array de inteiros basta você usar a api stream.

```
   int[] nros = {3,6,7,20,4,5,98,65,7,9,43,57,86,46,8,34,67};
   int maior = Arrays.stream(nros).max().getAsInt();
   System.out.println(maior);
```

[]'s

Comment: Não é um array é uma [BTree](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_B).